# Add background image to DataTable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am rendering a table using Datatables. I am also using bootstrap in my html page. I want to display a background image(responsive) in the body of the table and cannot exactly figure out how. I tried the following:

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="20px; background-image:'/static/img/rsz_background.jpg';">

<table id="{{tab.table_id}}" class="table table-hover table-bordered compact left" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" style="width:98% !important; background-image:'/static/img/rsz_background.jpg'">

<tbody style ="background-image:'/static/img/rsz_background.jpg' ">
```

None of the above seem to work. I noticed that when I try to change the background color, no changes are reflected in the body. I don't now if this a bootstrap issue. I am new to Web Dev, please suggest me what to do. 
Imports:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='css/query.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
<link href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='css/table.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  

<!-- For DataTable plugin -->
<link href= "//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What would be the correct order of imports?

Comment: Seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/owfh1q2w/2 You'll need to demonstrate your problem more effectively for help.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I missed the url part. Also, Only the header contain the image. Is there any way to display the image as background on the body part too?

Answer (score 3):

#### SOLUTION

Use CSS rule below instead of inlining CSS styles with `style` attribute, this is considered to be bad practice.

```css
.table-bg-dark {
    color: #FFF;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/800); 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Then you could use the following HTML:

```html
<div class="table-responsive table-bg-dark">
   <table id="{{tab.table_id}}" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

      <!-- skipped -->

   </table>
</div>
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqnz4mu3/1/) for code and demonstration.

#### NOTES

Include the following files:

```
<!-- Twitter Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='css/query.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
<link href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='css/table.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  

<!-- jQuery DataTables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.css"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Got to the root. The order in which I am including css and js files is impacting the background somehow. With the present order, I cannot display the background in the table body. If I change the order however my code cannot recognize the Datatables function. Can anyone give input on that?

Comment: @mini.1601, you're not including proper files, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Solved the issue by including bootstrap in body tag